# if statement is not executing within the function even the condition is true

Tags: python

The if statement is not executing in `deck()` function even the if condition is `True` always executing the else statement.

I always entered the letter in ask input variable which always exits `in` secret or random_word, for example if the `random_word` is "AAF" the i pass the value of ask whether "A" or "F"

```
import random
random_word = random.choice(open('sowpods.txt','r').read().split())
secret = [x for x in random_word]
print('secret: ', secret)
place = [' ' for x in range(len(random_word))]
print('place: ', place)
guessed = list()
chance = 0
play = True
print("Welcome to Hangman Game!")
print(random_word)

def board():

    ask = input("Please guess the letter: ").upper

    if ask in secret:
        return("ask in secret")
    else:
        print('ask not in secret')

board()
```

Output:

```
secret:  ['P', 'O', 'U', 'S', 'S', 'I', 'E']
place:  [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
Welcome to Hangman Game!
POUSSIE
Please guess the letter: P
ask not in secret
```

I want to execute the if statement not the else statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print out `ask` after entry (printing out, or otherwise examining, variables that seem to be misbehaving should generally be your *first* debugging step):

```
ask = input("Please guess the letter: ").upper
print(ask) # add this
```

If you do that, you should *immediately* see the problem:

```
<built-in method upper of str object at 0x7f977c1da3e8>
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It's a *function object* rather than the expected string, and it's because you're missing the actual parentheses required to *call* (rather than just refer to) the `upper` function. It should be:

```
ask = input("Please guess the letter: ").upper()
#                                    _________/\________
#                                   / This is important \
```

Answer (score 0):

The .upper method needs to be called with brackets and print("ask in secret") instead of return("ask in secret")

```
random_word = random.choice(open('sowpods.txt','r').read().split())
secret = [x for x in random_word]
print('secret: ', secret)
place = [' ' for x in range(len(random_word))]
print('place: ', place)
guessed = list()
chance = 0
play = True
print("Welcome to Hangman Game!")
print(random_word)

def board():

    ask = input("Please guess the letter: ").upper()

    if ask in secret:
        print("ask in secret")
    else:
        print('ask not in secret')

board()
```